# Locale-aware Perl regular expressions (matching word boundaries)

Tags: regex, perl, internationalization, locale

I'm currently somewhat stuck getting a regular expression in Perl (taken from an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990117/regular-expression-to-mask-strings-using-string-substitution) of mine) to match word characters from a non-ASCII locale (i.e., German umlauts).

I already tried various things such as setting the correct locale (using setlocale), converting data that I receive from MySQL to UTF8 (using decode_utf8), and so on... Unfortunately, to no avail. Google also did not help much.

Is there any chance to get the following regex locale-aware so that

```
$street = "Täststraße"; # I know that this is not orthographically correct
$street =~ s{
               \b (\w{0,3}) (\w*) \b
            }
            {
               $1 . ( '*' x length $2 )
            }gex;
```

ends up returning `$street = "Täs*******"` instead of `"Tästs***ße"`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would expect that the regex result in "Täs*******".  And this is what I get when I "use utf8" in a utf-8 encoded file with your code above.

(If everything is latin-1, that changes the behavior of the regex engine.  Hence the existence of `utf8::upgrade`.  See [Unicode::Semantics](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Unicode::Semantics).)

Edit: I see you fixed your post and that we agree on the expected result.  Basically, use Unicode::Semantics when you want Unicode semantics on your regexps.

Comment: That's weird... When run in a standalone fashion the code indeed works.

It turns out that "use locale" broke things... Once I removed that everything went back to normal.

Comment: Yeah, "use locale" should be avoided.  "use utf8" for if you have utf8 literals in utf8-encoded source code.  Otherwise, handle encoding with Encode, and use Unicode::Semantics when warranted.

Comment: Is "use locale" a bad idea in all circumstances? Is it/should it be deprecated?

Comment: Depends on whether or not you want the behavior of your program to depend on the environment and random data in /usr/share/i18n/locales.  If you need something to be locale dependent, why not just call the appropriate function directly?

Comment: good advice about `use utf8`; I put in all my programs now. One should perhaps [warn about \b boundaries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213800/is-there-something-like-a-counter-variable-in-regular-expression-replace/4214173#4214173) in patterns, though. They often surprise people!