# What is the best way to match only letters in a regex?

Tags: regex, perl, letters

I would really like to use \w but it also matches underscores so I'm going with [A-Za-z] which feels unnecessarily verbose and America centric. Is there a better way to do this? Something like [\w^_] (I doubt I got that syntax right)?

Comment: `[A-Za-z]` isn't America-centric, it's ASCII-centric.

Comment: @CanSpice, I'd say it's Latin-centric, as ASCII is only uses the latin alphabet.

Comment: @Axeman, Sources? AFAIK many Latin-derived languages have stressed vowels and letters. [A-Za-z] won't match neither Español nor Française. Even pure latin has the Æ glyph that is not inside ASCII. Which Latin are you talking about?

Comment: @Gzork, *Classical* 23 character Latin alphabet + the Medieval J, U, & W

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use `/[a-z]/i` or `/[[:alpha:]]/` just as well. In fact, `\w` includes numbers so that won't even work.

Comment: I take it the `i` makes it case-insensitive?

Answer (score 16):

Perhaps you mean `/[[:alpha:]]/`?  See [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) for the discussion of POSIX character classes.

Comment: I still don't think this take the international characters into consideration, since `:alpha:` is still `a-zA-Z`

Comment: I was wrong; the perldocs should be updated.  However it does include extra punctuations: `ʹʺʻˍˎˏːˑˬˮ̀́`

Comment: @vol7ron: The extra punctuation spills beyond the comment into your username. (Firefox 3.6.10 on Windows XP)

Comment: @Jon Purdy: ahh, I suspect that's a side effect of having unicode characters in output - another reason not to use :alpha:

Answer (score 14):

Just use `\p{L}` which means "any Unicode letter" and works in Perl (`/\p{L}/`). You probably need to `use utf8;`.

Answer (score 9):

Matching international (i.e non-ASCII) characters is kind of tough, and could depend on a lot of things. Check out this example:

```
#!perl -w

use strict;
use utf8;

my $string = "ä";

print "matched :alpha:\n"  if $string =~ /[[:alpha:]]/;
print "matched ^\\W0-9_\n" if $string =~ /[^\W0-9_]/;
print "matched [a-zA-Z]\n" if $string =~ /[a-zA-Z]/;
print "matched [a-z]i\n"   if $string =~ /[a-z]/i;
print "matched [A-z]\n"    if $string =~ /[A-z]/;
```

For me this results in

```
matched :alpha:
```

If you remove the `use utf8` then none of the regular expressions match.

Looking at [this very relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553215/locale-aware-perl-regular-expressions-matching-word-boundaries), it looks like you probably want to `use utf8` and check out [Unicode::Semantics](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Unicode::Semantics).

Of course, if you're using straight ASCII characters than any of the aforementioned regular expressions will work.

Comment: You have to be careful with \w and \W in Perl. It's a bit of a moving target lately, so I wouldn't depend on its definition.

Comment: What your editor is displaying as 'ä' may not be a letter in Perl. 'ä' = "\xE4" is not defined in the ASCII character set, by default Perl will use ASCII character classes for string that are not encoded as UTF8. Adding `use utf8;` will treat your source code as UTF8 and make "ä" a Unicode string. In the Unicode character set 'ä' is a alpha character. Compare `$string = "ä";` vs `$string = decode("iso-8859-1", "ä");` without `use utf8;`. In the first case Perl will see binary data, in the second the binary data is being interpreted as Latin-1 and converted to UTF-8.

Answer (score 6):

```
[^\W0-9_]

# or

[[:alpha:]]
```

See perldoc [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)

Answer (score 4):

A few options:

```
1. /[a-z]/i               # case insensitive
2. /[A-Z]/i               # case insensitive
3. /[A-z]/                # explicit range listing (capital 'A' to lowercase 'z')
4. /[[:alpha:]]/          # POSIX alpha character class
```

I recommend using either the case-insensitive, or the true way `/[a-zA-z]/`, unless you have a certain language preference in mind.

**Note:**

- Number 3 requires the capital 'A' first and then lowercase 'z' because of the order of the ASCII values; it does not work if you do the reverse: `a-Z`.  Also: *this method would fail the no-underscore criteria, since it includes* **[ \ ] ^ _ `**   .
- Number 4 will match on those additional language characters, but it also matches on:
  `ʹʺʻˍˎˏːˑˬˮ̀́`    (plus many others)

Comment: The `[A-z]` range includes a bunch of other characters.

Comment: You are correct there's a few brackets and extra characters, which would break the no-underscore criteria.  I've modified the answer. @flies, yes but I was incorrect.  Really the first two are the same method, just showing you can use different inputs.

Answer (score 0):

you're looking for internationalization in your regex? then you'll need to do something like this guy did: [JavaScript validation issue with international characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073412/javascript-validation-issue-with-international-characters)

explicitly match on all of the moon language letters :)

Comment: I don't see any moon letters in that regex, but it might just be because I'm reading it in the daylight.

Comment: When you see them, you're supposed to howl