# How do I recognize a "text" word via regex?

Tags: regex, perl

What perl regex matches a "word" in the following filename?

I have a series of file names in which some words appear more than once:

```
john_smith_on_alaska_trip_john_smith_0001.jpg
```

His wife's name is Olga, with an umlaut over the o, and there are a few other names with diacritics; all lower case, in my situation, but not simply English a-z. The .jpg has been temporarily stripped off for other reasons, and may be ignored for this discussion.

I want to remove the duplicate names/words. Something like this works fine in emacs:

```
s/(\b\w{3,}\b)(.*)(\b\1\b)/\1\2/
```

Run it once, the above turns to: `john_smith_on_alaska_trip__smith_0001.jpg`

Again:                           `john_smith_on_alaska_trip___0001.jpg`

In Perl, this does not work because `\w` includes the `_` as a word character.
Worse yet - the anchor, `\b` is anything other than those characters, and therefore doesn't separate on `_`.

My current solution is to replace all `_` with , do the deed, and revert. But, this seems such a fundamental requirement, I feel I must be missing something.

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to match only letters in a regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754097/what-is-the-best-way-to-match-only-letters-in-a-regex)

Comment: This question isn't a duplicate, he wants to include `_` in his match sometimes.

Comment: 1. Already found that comment.
2. It has so many false starts, it does not have the value it could. I imagine most people who find that page walk away in frustration.
3. For key useful pages, perhaps like that one, a knowledgeable person with a few minutes of cleanup time might save a lot of time in the long run (if people understand it, they may not ask a new one). This is only my second day with Perl, so I won't take the chance of wrecking it by [try] to fix it... :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Character Class `\p{Alpha}`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html) and [Lookbehind and Lookahead assertions](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Looking-ahead-and-looking-behind) in place of word boundaries to ensure that the each word is a whole word instead of a substring:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = "john_smith_on_alaska_trip_john_smith_0001_johnsmith.jpg";

1 while $file =~ s{
    (?<!\p{Alpha}) ( \p{Alpha}++ )     # Word surrounded by non-word chars
    .* \K                              # Keep everything before this point
    (?<!\p{Alpha}) \1 (?!\p{Alpha})    # Strip duplicate word 
}{}x;

print "$file\n";
```

Outputs:

```
john_smith_on_alaska_trip___0001_johnsmith.jpg
```

<kbd>[Live Demo](https://eval.in/210026)</kbd>

Comment: Welcome to your day 2 with Perl.  Note, there are quite a few regex concepts I used in this solution, so I would recommend a general reading of [perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html) and [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) whenever you're ready to start picking up more re tools.

Comment: 100% on the money.
And, learned a lot - \K, ++, (? - all new (to me :-). I'd vote it up, but don't have the rep.

You've been so helpful, I hate to ask, what does the '1' mean (to the left of 'while'), haven't found that yet.

Comment: Because we're modifying the string back to front, we can't utilize the `/g` Modifier.  Instead, I just put the regex in a loop with the regex as the condition, and a dummy expression as the BLOCK.  It's equivalent to `while ($file =~ s/.../.../) { }` except using the statement modifier form of `while`.

Comment: The statement is in the form:  1 while ( $f =~ s/.../.../ ) {} x;
It's the '1' in the beginning and 'x' at the end that have me confused. They seem unnecessary.

Comment: The [`/x` Modifier](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#%2fx) enables arbitrary whitespace and comments within the regex.  Additionally, I'm using braces `s{}{}` as an alternative regex delimiter instead of `s///`.  This is because I consider it easier to read when the regex spans lines.  Finally, for the alternative `while` format, read [perlsyn - Statement Modifiers](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Statement-Modifiers).

Comment: Got it - you were using the form: <statement> while <condition>; Since I didn't recognize "1" as a statement, the structure made no sense to me. Again, thanks for your time - the \K was a totally new concept.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split` to separate your string into its constituent pieces and then check for duplicates using a hash:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = 'john_smith_on_alaska_trip_john_smith_0001.jpg';
my @words = split /_/, $string;

my %count;
foreach my $word (@words) {
    $word = '' if ++$count{$word} > 1;
}

print join('_', @words), "\n";
```

#### Output:

```
john_smith_on_alaska_trip___0001.jpg
```

Alternatively, you could use `uniq` from [`List::MoreUtils`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils#uniq-LIST) to get the unique words, although this will change your output slightly by eliminating the consecutive underscores after `trip`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::MoreUtils 'uniq';

my $string = 'john_smith_on_alaska_trip_john_smith_0001.jpg';
my @words = split /_/, $string;

print join('_', uniq @words), "\n";
```

#### Output:

```
john_smith_on_alaska_trip_0001.jpg
```